# Visual Studio SSDT BI 2015 for VS 2013 - SSIS only opens Advanced Editors

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, bids, ssdt-bi

Not sure what happened here. I had some issues with versions of SSDT-BI. In any case, the last one I installed was SSDT-BI for Visual Studio 2013.

Now when I open my integration services projects. If I click on, for example, an ole db source, it goes directly to the advanced editor. If I right click and select Edit instead of Advanced Editor - it still opens the advanced editor.

Has anyone experienced this before? I'm not sure where to begin looking. I feel like my keyboard has a key stuck down or something, but not sure which one.

Images for example:

[image: Clicking-Edit]

Clicking Edit leads to the advanced dialog:

[image: advanced-dialog]

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you create a new project?

Comment: I just created a new project, added a data flow, then added an OLE DB Source. Double Clicked and received the Advanced Editor.

Comment: Well that rules out corruption in the existing packages.   Hopefully somebody else has another theory.   : )

Answer (score 1):

[Advanced editor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187063(v=sql.105).aspx) is the only editor available for those objects that do not expose a custom user interface.

It sounds like your installation is now corrupt.